# How can i send data and get data via angular to socket server

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, socket.io

currently i am trying to send and get the data via angular client to socket server and from socket server to angular i need to get data i able to push the data but i need to know how can i push data to the api which is there in socket server and get data from the api to socket server and emit it to client

below is my

**For sending data from angular client to socket server**

- **component code**

  constructor(public socketService: SocketioService){

  ```
     }

    ngOnInit(){
       this.socketService.setupSocketConnection();
     }
   // For sending post request
     sendMsg(){
       this.socketService.sendData(this.title);
     }
      // For getting the request
     getMsg(){

      this.socketService.getMsg().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  ```

**Angular service code**

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

socket;
  constructor() {

  }
  setupSocketConnection() {
    this.socket = io(environment.SOCKET_ENDPOINT);


  }
  // for posting data
  sendData(values){
    console.log(values);
    this.socket.emit('my message', values);
  }
   //for getting data
  getMsg(){
   return Observable.create((observer) => {
    this.socket.on('grabMsg', (message) => {
        observer.next(message);
    });
});
  }
```

**Node server code**

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hey Socket.io</h1>');
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('my message', (msg) => {
      //here i want to consume api like 
      // localhost:3000(post) {"title":"ss"}

    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
  socket.on('grabMsg', () => {
        //here i want to consume api like 
      // localhost:3000(get)
      let ms = 'max'
      io.emit(ms);
  });
});
http.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

so here how can i  send and post data in socket server
in short i will send data to from angular client to socket server then to some api

Comment: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket

Answer (score 1):

```
//server-side
socket.on('grabMsg', () => {
  let ms = 'max'
  io.emit(ms);
});

//client-side
this.socket.on('grabMsg', (message) => {
    observer.next(message);
});
```

In the above code you are using socket.on on both client and server-side also, use one as emit as one as on according to your requirement.

And in below code you are only emitting and there is the first parameter for emitting (any text enclosed in side quote) like below code

```
socket.on('grabMsg', () => {
  let ms = 'max'
  io.emit("thatText",ms);
});
```

the same text(thatText) should be on client-side too, like

```
this.socket.on('thatText', (message) => {
   console.log(message)
});
```

Comment: Ok but how can get the response which was emiited by get request to client

Comment: That is because this socket.io id built on the top of the event emitter module (built-in module of node.js) [You can refer this documentation for more details] (https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) Socket.io uses this package to perform emit and listening event, and on the server-side when you create a socket server there is a default option that serves the client but here you imported that package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nodeJs [eventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) API. So you can emit an event by eventEmitter when someone hits your endpoint(GET request) and listen that event inside your socket server and vice-versa.

More details:- [Custom Events in Node.js with Express framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232500/custom-events-in-node-js-with-express-framework)

Answer (score 0):

```
    export class LiveSocket implements OnInit {

    //define a socket
    public socket = new WebSocket(environment.SOCKET_ENDPOINT);

    ngOnInit() {

     // Add an event listener for when a connection is open
    this.socket.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection opened. Ready to send messages.');
      // Send a message to the server
      this.socket.send('message');
    };

    // Add an event listener for when a message is received from the server
    this.socket.onmessage = (message) => {
     //handle getting data from server 
     var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
     console.log(data)
    };
  }
}
```